# IF else condition not working properly for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am basically been working with SQL Server. However, recently I have moved to Oracle and I am trying a simple if else statement but it is giving error in Oracle SQL Developer. Below is the query which is not executing

```
              IF (? = 'MEANING') THEN    
                      SELECT rv_meaning_l1 vc_result 
                      FROM   TableA
                      WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
                      AND    rv_low_value = '10';  
        
              ELSIF (? = 'ABBREVIATION') THEN
                          SELECT rv_abbreviation_l1  vc_result
                          FROM   TableA
                          WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
                          AND    rv_low_value = '10';
              END IF;
```

The value of **?** will come from parameter of Power BI paginated report through ODBC connection. However, I am getting error and this **if block** is not executing at all. I tried to check in sql developer by replacing ? with **'MEANING'** but still the code is not executing.

```
             IF ('MEANING' = 'MEANING') THEN    
                      SELECT rv_meaning_l1 vc_result 
                      FROM   TableA
                      WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
                      AND    rv_low_value = '10';  
        
              ELSIF ('MEANING' = 'ABBREVIATION') THEN
                          SELECT rv_abbreviation_l1  vc_result
                          FROM   TableA
                          WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
                          AND    rv_low_value = '10';
              END IF;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only [use `IF` in a PL/SQL context](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-18777904-23F6-4F6D-8B41-46BABF00BA03), so your code would need to be between `BEGIN` and `END`, and you would need to select into something, which isn't really want you want.

You don't need that form of logic or two queries here though, you can use a single query with a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96) to decide the column that's selected; assuming both columns are the same data type:

```
SELECT CASE(?
         WHEN 'MEANING' THEN rv_meaning_l1
         WHEN 'ABBREVIATION' THEN rv_abbreviation_l1
         ELSE NULL
         END vc_result 
FROM   TableA
WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
AND    rv_low_value = '10';
```

The `ELSE NULL` is optional as that's the default if nothing matches, but I've put it in to make it clearer and so you can return some other value if you want, if the variable is neither expected value.

If you want to test it in SQL Developer then [use a bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B52D6F2E-A28A-48B6-B73F-6A9D018BD107) in the form it recognises:

```
var arg varchar2(10);
exec :arg := 'MEANING';

SELECT CASE(:arg
         WHEN 'MEANING' THEN rv_meaning_l1
         WHEN 'ABBREVIATION' THEN rv_abbreviation_l1
         ELSE NULL
         END vc_result 
FROM   TableA
WHERE  rv_domain = 'CLAIM TYPE'
AND    rv_low_value = '10';
```

You can read more about the [`VARIABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/VARIABLE.html#GUID-B4A0DAA3-B6E0-42F7-89B0-EF9C41F02FA3) and [`EXECUTE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6) commands in the SQL*Plus manual; SQL Developer uses most of the same commands.

Comment: I would say that exactly the same code should be used in almost any DBMS including SQL Server instead of flow control statements. Because it actually doesn't decide what source (object) should be used, but what *expression* should be returned. And according to SQL rules and consumer specifics (BI tool) this expression should have the same data type across execution, which doesn't require switching to conditional return.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your solution worked like a charm.